# Only after SMC reset will Windows 10 under Boot Camp start

Tags: bootcamp

I recently installed Windows 10 via Boot Camp. The first time everything goes well, but after booting back into macOS, I get an error message on macOS. It seems that error message is messing up the next time I am trying to boot into Boot Camp and Windows 10. That second time it seems to start Windows, but eventually defaults back to macOS.

I have figured out that if I do an SMC reset, I can boot up Windows, but I first have to pick a restore point to make Windows work, and use Windows. Bit cumbersome.

I have a brand new 2017 iMac 27"/3.8QC/8GB/2TB

[image: Your computer was restarted because of a problem]